# What does ("{0,1} ", num); mean?

Tags: c#

New to C# and I am trying to understand a statement

```
foreach (int num in numQuery)
{
    Console.Write("{0,1} ", num);
}
```

I am confused about what is that `{0, 1}` doing there. If it is `"{0}"`, then it is pretty clear, but what does `{0, 1}` mean?

Comment: 0 is the placeholder 1 is the size of the field so that you can display a columnar result. You can read about this on msdn by looking at [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) under the Controlling Spacing section.

Comment: And also note that it can also be written as `Console.Write($"{num,1}");` in C# 6

Comment: The String.Format link is great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it is a [custom numeric format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx), but matter of fact Charles is right in his comment:

> 0 is the placeholder 1 is the size of the field so that you can display a columnar result. You can read about this on MSDN by looking at [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) under the Controlling Spacing section)

Comment: Thank you for your the update. The String.Format link is quite helpful and has very clear examples.